# Convertir un string a char en C++ sin usar el método c_str() y la función strcpy

Tags: c++, string

¿Qué otra forma de convertir un string a char sin usar el método c_str() y la función strcpy existe?

Answer (score 1):

No se puede convertir un `std::string` a `char` de la misma manera que no puedes convertir un [rosario anglicano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosario_(anglicanismo)) en una cuenta, ni una escalera en un [escalón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escal%C3%B3n), ni una cadena en un [eslabón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eslab%C3%B3n), …

---

Si lo que quieres es obtener un puntero a los datos de un `std::string` para extraer un `char` del mismo tienes dos alternativas:

- `c_str`: Obtiene una cadena de caracteres al estilo [c](/questions/tagged/c), es decir: una cadena de caracteres finalizada con el carácter nulo (`\0`).
- `data`: Obtiene los datos almacenados en el búfer de `std::string`, no hay garantías de que contenga el carácter nulo al finalizar los datos.

Pero si lo que realmente quieres es leer un carácter de la cadena, usa el operador de indizado (los corchetes `[]`) o la función `at`:

```
std::string h{"Hola Mundo!"};

std::cout << h[0] << '\n'; // Muestra H
std::cout << h.at(5) << '\n'; // Muestra M
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sencilla es usando un bucle for y la función str.length() para determinar la longitud del string. El dato tipo char debe almacenar un espacio vacio y su tamaño debe ser mayor o igual al del string:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace  std;

int main()
{
    int longitud;
    string str = { "uvuwewe onyetenyevwe ugwemuhwem osas"};
    char nombre[60] = { "" };
    longitud = str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        nombre[i] = str[i];
    }

    cout << "\tNombre: " << nombre << endl;
}
```

Comment: Porqué el `cstdlib`?, es innecesario...

Comment: @nikomaster la edición que propones no es correcta, pues intentas modificar la respuesta del usuario con una tuya y estas con eso cambiando el contenido, si tienes una propuesta alterna entonces publicala como respuesta